# Get every n-hour data from database with tolerance

Tags: python, mysql, sql, datetime, between

I have a MySQL database in which I write data every 10 minutes. i.e.:

```
+---------------------+
| datetime            |
+---------------------+
| 2018-09-03 13:01:49 |
| 2018-09-03 12:51:49 |
| 2018-09-03 12:41:49 |
+---------------------+
```

In my Python code I want to get just rows which are "exactly" n-hour old, i.e.:

```
+---------------------+
| datetime            |
+---------------------+
| 2018-09-03 13:01:49 |
| 2018-09-03 12:01:49 |
| 2018-09-03 11:01:49 |
| 2018-09-03 10:01:49 |
| 2018-09-03 09:01:49 |
| 2018-09-03 08:01:49 |
+---------------------+
```

I have this code which returns data I want:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT max(datetime) FROM temperatures')
last_record_datetime = cursor.fetchone()
last_record_min = last_record_datetime[0].minute

query = f'SELECT * FROM temperatures WHERE DATETIME LIKE "%:%{last_record_min}:%" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20'
cursor.execute(query)
query_result = cursor.fetchall()
```

And here comes my question: If I will reboot the system, or there will be some problem or delay, and minutes in datetime of last record and records before the last one will not corresponding, I will get empty reply from database (because query `... LIKE "22"` not match with query `... LIKE "21"`).

So, what is the best way to get data from the database with some tolerance (let's say +- 4,99 min)?

Comment: How large is the database? The reason I ask is pandas supports a wide array of convenient functions for this purpose that get messy with SQL.

Comment: The database is pretty small now - it has 4 columns and about 4k rows. But in a few years it could have millions of rows. Actualy in this case I'm getting only 20 last records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write your data approximately every 10 minutes, it means that you want to fetch every 6th row, when you order by `datetime`.

You could try this:

```
select @rn := 1;

select `datetime` from (
    select @rn := @rn + 1 rn, `datetime` from temperatures
    order by `datetime` desc
) where mod(rn, 6) = 1
--limit 20
```

This is alternative approach, it will calculate how close datetime is to be"full hour" away from your latest date and it will filter based on that (it allows times to vary by 5 minutes):

```
select @dt := max(`datetime`) from temperatures;

select * from (
    select `datetime`, 
           mod(abs(timestampdiff(minuite,@dt,`datetime`)), 60) minDiff
    from temperatures
) a where minDiff < 5 or minDiff > 55
--limit 20
```

Comment: I thought the same solution, but in case that my temperature sensor will not response i.e. for 4 times, every 6th row will not gets me result I want but it will be shifted.

Comment: "I thought the same solution, but in case that my temperature sensor will not response i.e. for 4 times, every 6th row will not gets me result I want but it will be shifted." Buy a new one  that does response every time @user3861588 You can't magical write working code with bad responding  hardware..

Comment: @MichałTurczyn : The alternative approach seems exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let say u need only data 1-hour or less old and datetime is your column name.

```
select * from temperatures where TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, datetime, NOW()) <= 1 ;
```

Comment: I don't need 3 hour old data but every 1 hour old data till "now", please follow my example.

Comment: @user3861588  replace 3 with 1 and change = with <= 1

Comment: I need exactly 1 hour old data, exactly 2 old data, exactly 3 hour old data... Let's say it's 18:05, so I want data from 18:05, 17:05, 16:05, 15:05, 14:05... no more, no less. But with some tolerance (+- 4.99 min)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the records around the last record time, you should try to look for time differences between the last recorded time, something like

```
SELECT * FROM temperatures WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN DATE_SUB({last_record_min}, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND DATE_ADD({last_record_min}, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20
```